# Looking for an anti-drow "thundering" warhammer

Tags: dnd-3.5e, weapons, dnd-3e, content-identification

Many years ago, our group played a module that was, I believe, either 3e or 3.5e Dungeons & Dragons that contained a warhammer. Whenever this warhammer was in the presence of drow, the wielder would hear thundering drums and feel the urge to attack the drow. I had thought that it was Whelm from the Return to White Plume Mountain module, but I can't find any stats on Whelm that included this feature.

Was there another such weapon that anyone can find? Or was it perhaps a custom weapon or addition to Whelm that my DM came up with?

Comment: Would you please describe the setting of the module's dungeon or some details from an encounter or two?

Comment: Were you playing in a custom setting? Was it Greyhawk?

Answer (score 5):

There is a +3 warhammer known as "Craemmol’s Hammer" on page 121 of the *Player's Guide to the Faerun*. If a drow is within 60 feet of its wielder, the weapon makes a loud ringing sound like a huge bell. As a full round action, the wielder can also determine the precise location of the nearest drow within 60' radius, as well as the total number of drow.

It is stated that the weapon used to belong to a dwarf known for his battle prowess and greed. Perhaps your DM added the urge to attack drow as an extra flavour.

<sub>PS: Regarding the famous warhammer "Whelm" from the *White Plume Mountain*, its 3.5e incarnation was detailed in [free-to-download adventure](http://archive.wizards.com/default.asp?x=dnd/oa/20051207a) in 2005. Whelm is described as a legacy item with abilities "Sense Giants", "Locate Object", "Sense Goblinoids" and "Intelligent Legacy". None of these are related to the drow, as implied in the question.</sub>